# Represent return statement in flow chart

Tags: c++, function, return, flowchart

I am trying to figure out how return statements are represented in flowcharts.
For example having the function:

```
    int check(int x){
       int y=2;
       if(x>5) return x+1;
       cout<<"small value"<<endl;
       return y;
    }
```

Is there a proper way to draw the return statements of the above function in a flow chart?

Comment: Would that not simply be an arrow to the terminator? (after setting the return value to `x` in this case).

Comment: Yes thank you, I suppose this is the way to do it, but this way the flowchart can be identical to a function where we pass x by reference and have an if else statement, but i don't think flowcharts are meant to handle this kind of details

Comment: The `return` is not the termination point of the function.  The final `}` is the termination point, which is where any object destructors for automatic variables at that scope are called.  Map the closing `}` to the flowchart's terminator.

Comment: Like any other kind of goto statement, that is, with an arrow to the destination.

Comment: A more interesting question is how you represent an exception in the language of flowcharts. There is at least one potential exception hidden in the `<<`.

Answer (score 1):

I had spent some time searching for this. but seems like there's no explicit answer for this. The key thing to understand is

> flowchart has one starting point. However, a flowchart can have as many ending points as needed.

and we can say a return statement is a kind of termination.
So it can be represented with the same symbol(Oval) as End/terminator.
I came to this conclusion, after referring to this link: https://er.yuvayana.org/flowchart-representation-symbol-and-basic-blocks/

Answer (score 0):

When you make a flowchart for a function the parameters are the inputs for the algorithm and the return is the output. so after the start symbol an input/out figure will do the work and since the return is the function´s output another input/output shape will do also the work.

[Proposed Flowchart for your function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSV4t.png)